# API to enumerate the blocks from a specific day

Tags: blockchain, blocks, explorers, external-api, query

I'm trying to find an API that lists all the blocks from a specific day, as we can do with bitcoin:

https://blockchain.info/pt/blocks/1515628800000?format=json

I've searched [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/) and [blockcypher.com](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/ethereum/) APIs, as well as other ones and found nothing. Some APIs can list the latest blocks, but that's not what I need.

Is there any ethereum API similar to the blockchain.info API that can show all the blocks from a specific day?

Comment: Dear @karliwson, Did you find my answer helpful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no Web API, but you can perform this using SQL.

You can do it simply with "[Presto Ethereum Connector](https://github.com/xiaoyao1991/presto-ethereum)" (https://github.com/xiaoyao1991/presto-ethereum)

Using Presto Ethereum, you can query the blocks using an SQL command. You can base the *where* condition on *block_timestamp*.

Bellow is the structure of the "block" table provided by Presto Ethereum:

```
DESCRIBE block;
Column                 | Type               | Extra | Comment
-----------------------------------------------------------
block_number           | bigint             |       |
block_hash             | varchar(66)        |       |
block_parenthash       | varchar(66)        |       |
block_nonce            | varchar(18)        |       |
block_sha3uncles       | varchar(66)        |       |
block_logsbloom        | varchar(514)       |       |
block_transactionsroot | varchar(66)        |       |
block_stateroot        | varchar(66)        |       |
block_miner            | varchar(42)        |       |
block_difficulty       | bigint             |       |
block_totaldifficulty  | bigint             |       |
block_size             | integer            |       |
block_extradata        | varchar            |       |
block_gaslimit         | double             |       |
block_gasused          | double             |       |
block_timestamp        | bigint             |       |
block_transactions     | array(varchar(66)) |       |
block_uncles           | array(varchar(66)) |       |
```